# How to copy resources from Package to App

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Good Evening,

I made a Package which has defined a class and some resources. Defined class uses those resources.

```
 Package
 Sources
   ┝ UnicodeData
   ｜    ┝ flatUnicode.txt
   ｜    ┕ glyphNames.txt
   ┕ UnicodeNames
         ┕ UnicodeNames.swift
```

In package manifest they are defined as:

```
       ....
       targets: [
            .target(
                name: "UnicodeNames",
                resources: [
                    .copy("UnicodeData")]
            ),
       ....
```

I call resources from class by:

```
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        if let myResource = bundle.path(forResource: "flatUnicode", ofType: "txt")  {
        ....
```

I can add package to an application, it is visible under *Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content*  and *Package Dependency*. I can compile it and run, but resources are never found and app crashes. When I'm looking inside an app (*Show Package Content* from Finder, resources delivered by package do not exist inside)

How to copy resources from a Package to an App?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> When you build your Swift package, Xcode treats each target as a Swift module. If a target includes resources, Xcode creates a resource bundle and an internal static extension on Bundle to access it for each module. Use the extension to locate package resources. For example, use the following to retrieve the URL of a property list you bundle with your package:
> let settingsURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "settings", withExtension: "plist")

> **Important** Always use Bundle.module when you access resources. A package shouldn’t make assumptions about the exact location of a resource.

> If you want to make a package resource available to apps that depend on your Swift package, declare a public constant for it. For example, use the following to expose a property list file to apps that use your Swift package:
> `let settingsURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "settings", withExtension: "plist")`